# Why is my maven build not finding Netty's EventLoopGroup class when executing?

Tags: java, maven, netty

I wrote my code following Netty's documentation, then I execute:

```
mvn package
```

It builds successfully. Then I run:

```
java -jar target/netty-listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And it promts me with this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup   at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
> java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
> java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)    at
> java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)   at
> java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)    at
> sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
> at
> sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 7 more

To my understanding, the JRE is not finding Netty's EventLoopGroup Class in execution time. In Eclipse, I see the netty-all dependency on Maven's dependency tab and EventLoopGroup is there. I've tried to change Netty's version multiple times but it does not work.

Here is my main code:

```
package paplistener;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

public class PAPServer 
{
    
    private int port;
    
    public PAPServer(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new CommandDecoder(),
                                            new PAPServerHandler());
                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
            
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();
            
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int port = 8080;
        
        if(args.length > 0)
        {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        
        new PAPServer(port).run();
    }
    
}
```

It is almost the exact code from Netty's documentation, but it adds a decoder in the beginning of the pipeline.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>neurony.listener</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-listener</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.53.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>paplistener.PAPServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                          ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

EDIT1: Added maven-shade-plugin to pom.xml but the (same) problem persists.

Lines added to pom:

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Main-Class>paplistener.PAPServer</Main-Class>
                                <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
```

EDIT2: added artifactSet to pom.xml but it didn't work

```
<artifactSet>
    <includes>
            <include>io.netty:*</include>
    </includes>
</artifactSet>
```

I tried * : * as well, just as Yuri G. suggested.

EDIT3: Contents of unzip -l:

> Archive:  netty-listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar   Length      Date    Time
> Name
>
> ---
>
> ```
>     0  10-29-2020 10:17   META-INF/
>   266  10-29-2020 10:17   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
>     0  10-29-2020 10:17   paplistener/
>  2903  10-29-2020 10:17   paplistener/PAPCommandHandler.class
>  2554  10-29-2020 10:17   paplistener/PAPServer.class
>  2103  10-29-2020 10:17   paplistener/CommandDecoder.class
>  2834  10-29-2020 10:17   paplistener/PAPServerHandler.class
>  1319  10-29-2020 10:17   paplistener/PAPServer$1.class
>     0  10-29-2020 10:17   META-INF/maven/
>     0  10-29-2020 10:17   META-INF/maven/neurony.listener/
>     0  10-29-2020 10:17   META-INF/maven/neurony.listener/netty-listener/
>  3572  10-28-2020 12:29   META-INF/maven/neurony.listener/netty-listener/pom.xml
>   125  10-29-2020 10:17   META-INF/maven/neurony.listener/netty-listener/pom.properties
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 15676                     13 files
> ```

It seems like netty is not being copied to the jar file. But I still don't know how to solve it. I'll link here the generated .classpath (I guess Eclipse generated it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources" output="target/test-classes" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 8 [1.8.0_121]"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/io/netty/netty-all/4.1.30.Final/netty-all-4.1.30.Final.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/io/netty/netty-all/4.1.30.Final/netty-all-4.1.30.Final-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javassist/javassist/3.12.1.GA/javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javassist/javassist/3.12.1.GA/javassist-3.12.1.GA-sources.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin element should not be inside build->pluginManagement->plugins, but inside build->plugins. Like this

```
<project>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <transformers>
              <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
              </transformer>
            </transformers>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</project>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. In the end, Yuri was right, but I needed to write the plugin outside the pluginManagement tag.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the classpath. Eclipse manages its own classpath, that's why it works in Eclipse.

The easiest way to create a `jar` file that can be executed simply by `java -jar` is to use a `maven-shade-plugin`. You can check the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) for how to create an executable jar with maven-shade-plugin.

**Update**:
You need to configure which artifacts to include in the shaded jar as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#artifactSet). For example if you want include all dependencies including transitive, you can do as following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <configuration>
       <artifactSet>
          <includes>
             <include>*:*</include>
          </includes>
       </artifactSet>
       <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>paplistener.PAPServer</Main-Class>
                            <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

You can see all available configuration in the doc's page https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html

Comment: I did what you told me but the problem persists. I edited my post to show the new pom.xml lines. I don't know if it is a problem with classpath because maven builds (compiles) everything. I don't know why the problem happens during execution

Comment: Do I have to add artifacts (dependencies) manually?

Comment: I tried to include the artifactSet. I used <include>*:*</include>. Then I tried <include>io.netty:*</include>. Both didn't work. I really don't know why this is happening.

Comment: can you share the output of `unzip -l <jar file>`

Comment: I edited my post. It seems like it is copying netty to the jar file. Posted the .classpath as well

Comment: @MatheusHemerlyRisso to make it clear I've edited the answer with the complete configuration for the shade plugin in your case. If it doesn't work, please double check your config and read for more details the shade plugin documentation https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html